# How to generate a subreport using java

Tags: java, jasper-reports, javabeans, subreport

How to generate a *JasperReports* report (including) subreport by passing values from *JavaBean* class without writing query in report

Comment: By writing code that generate a report by passing values from java bean class without writing query in iReport.

Answer (score 0):

You could use DynamicReports API, which is based on JasperReports. It enables you to do everything from within your beans.

[DynamicReports](http://www.dynamicreports.org/) 
 [Samples](http://www.dynamicreports.org/examples/examples-overview) and [Practical example](http://www.mkyong.com/java/reporting-in-java-using-dynamicreports-and-jasperreports/).

 Of course you will still need to use a sql query to get the data source, but this way you can avoid using iReports.